# Data outside of Request is Undefined

Tags: module, web-scraping, request, node-modules, cheerio

Section that is invoking the code.

`** index.js **`

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var RagialJS     = express();

RagialJS.get('/scrape', function(req, res){

  console.log(getItemJSON("Minor Brisket", "Renewal"));

}) // End RagialJS.get
```

I expect this to print out a JSON object but returns undefined.

`** getItemJSON() **`

```
// Returns buy, sell, and metrics of item as a JSON
function getItemJSON(itemName, server) {
  var url = getItemURL(itemName, server);
  request(url, function(error, response, html) {
    if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);

        // Logic that parses and puts data in JSON here...

        // console.log(json); works here
        return json;
        } else {
          console.log(error);
        }
  }); // End request
// console.log(json); DOESN'T works here
}
```

The problem here is that if I `console.log(json);` before the request ends then it works fine but if I do it outside of the request (or another function) then it returns undefined. (Same problem for `getItemURL()`)

Is there a way to resolve this problem? Or am I overlooking some fundamental idea about requests for data?

[Full Source Code if interested](https://github.com/chernandez7/RagialJS/blob/master/index.js)

Any help or comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the main problem is that you are doing async calls and expecting to get the results in a sincronous way.

The request function second parameter is a callback that is called when the request gets a response.

So the problem is:

```
request(url, function(error, response, html) {
    console.log('A');
}) // End Request
console.log('B');
```

You are expecting that the console output is:

```
A
B
```

but the output is:

```
B
A
```

That's because the function is asyncronous and it will be called when the request gets a response, and the code continues executing while the request is waiting for that response.

*I have downloaded your code and changed few things to test it, tell me if you want me to send it to you.

Comment: Good explanation but it is useless without the code. It's very odd that you would make changes and then just send them privately. This should not have been marked "answered'.